# Oracle Sql query for report in one record large data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot

Dears
I need to generate report for number of transactions per employee per date

Each employee have 10 records each record include number 9f transaction on its day

```
Emp1  16/10/2020  50
Emp1  15/10/2020  30
Emp1  14/10/2020  70
```

I need query to return this data in one record as

```
Emp  14/10  15/10  16/10 
___  _____  _____  _____
Emp1  70      30     50
```

How can i write such query?

Comment: If you know the days in advance, it's not bad. But if not, the SQL language has a very strict rule requiring you to know the number and types of result columns in advance, at query compile time. As long as you can do that, you can PIVOT your way to success. Even SELECT * queries do this, because the table definitions are known and sufficiently static. Otherwise, you have to do it in three steps: **1)** Run a query to get info about what columns you need. **2)** Use data from 1 to build a new SQL statement dynamically, with all the security/risk that involves. **3)** Run the query from 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Conditional aggregation such as

```
SELECT Employee, SUM(CASE WHEN day = date'2020-10-14' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "14/10",
                 SUM(CASE WHEN day = date'2020-10-15' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "15/10",
                 SUM(CASE WHEN day = date'2020-10-16' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "16/10"
  FROM t
 GROUP BY Employee
```

or `PIVOT` clause such as

```
SELECT Employee, SUM("14/10") AS "14/10", 
                 SUM("15/10") AS "15/10", 
                 SUM("16/10") AS "16/10"
  FROM t
 PIVOT 
 (
  COUNT(*) FOR day IN (date'2020-10-14' AS "14/10",
                       date'2020-10-15' AS "15/10",
                       date'2020-10-16' AS "16/10") 
 )
 GROUP BY Employee
```

in order to pivot your results in a static manner, eg, in both cases you have to add all the columns into the query whichever date value is needed. Rather, you can use a function including `SYS_REFCURSOR` such as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Transactions_RS RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols      VARCHAR2(32767);  
BEGIN

  SELECT LISTAGG( 'SUM(CASE WHEN day = '''||day||''' 
                            THEN 1 ELSE 0 
                        END) AS "'||TO_CHAR(day,'dd/mm')||'"' , ',' )
          WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY day )
    INTO v_cols
    FROM (
          SELECT DISTINCT day
            FROM t
          );

  v_sql :=
  'SELECT Employee, '|| v_cols ||'
     FROM t
    GROUP BY Employee'; 

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

and then call from SQL Developer's console in order to return the number of transactions per each day pivoted :

```
SQL> DECLARE
    v_transactions SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
   :v_transactions := Get_Transactions_RS;
END;
/

SQL> PRINT v_transactions ;
```